# C# - Cannot access a closed stream

Tags: c#, stream, itext, filestream, memorystream

My code for PDF creation with iTextSharp version 5.5.13.2 is returning error, "Cannot access a closed stream."
I am unsure how this error could arise as I have my code encapsulated within reaches of Using statement. Debugging results in app going to break state.
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

Comment: Which line of code causes that.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1232840/Cannot-access-a-closed-stream-error

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? (P.S You should also probably explicitly mention you're using iTextSharp in your question/ tags)

Comment: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Document.cs#L64 _might_ be related.

Comment: A typical cause for this would be that the stream is disposed by some user of the stream, possibly the pdfwriter or document. Some classes take a "keepOpen" parameter to avoid this behavior.

Comment: @mjwills I don't know the specific line as the debugger is returning break state.

Comment: @MindSwipe I am using iTextSharp version v5.5.13.2. Your other point noted, question edited.

Comment: @JonasH could you suggest any alteration to this code?

Comment: Taking a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/1521211fc3fa0e9402fe855300bb240302de0508/src/core/iTextSharp/text/DocWriter.cs#L214) it closes the `os` (output stream, your `ms` parameter in `PdfWriter.GetInstance`) depending on if `closeStream` is true or false. And it just happens that [`closeStream`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/1521211fc3fa0e9402fe855300bb240302de0508/src/core/iTextSharp/text/DocWriter.cs#L348) is a property. So all you should need to do is set `writer.CloseStream = false;` after `GetInstance`

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks, this sorted this error. But now a second error has cropped up, "PDF Header Signature not found". Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, but that's an entirely different question. I'm writing up a more elaborate answer to this question right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the (deprecated) iTextSharp 5.5.13.2 [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp), I can find the source for the `DocWriter` (base class of `PdfWriter`) and it's `Close` method [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/1521211fc3fa0e9402fe855300bb240302de0508/src/core/iTextSharp/text/DocWriter.cs#L214)

```cs
public virtual void Close() {
    open = false;
    os.Flush();
    if (closeStream)
        os.Close();
}
```

`os` in this case is whatever was passed as the second argument to `PdfWriter.GetInstance` (`ms` in your case). Using Ctrl + F I can find the source for `closeStream`, which happens to be a property exposes as `CloseStream` [here](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/1521211fc3fa0e9402fe855300bb240302de0508/src/core/iTextSharp/text/DocWriter.cs#L348)

```cs
public virtual bool CloseStream {
    get {
        return closeStream;
    }
    set {
        closeStream = value;
    }
}
```

And all together `Close` is automatically called by the [`Dispose` method](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/1521211fc3fa0e9402fe855300bb240302de0508/src/core/iTextSharp/text/DocWriter.cs#L369) of `DocWriter`

```cs
public virtual void Dispose() {
    Close();
}
```

So, if you don't want the `PdfWriter` to close your `ms`, you'll need to set `writer.CloseStream = false;` before your `PdfWriter` gets closed